# Ionic 3 Import Custom Component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm stuck with importing a custom component into a page in Ionic 3. This was relatively trivial in Ionic 2 but I cant seem to get it to work in Ionic 3.

I have an existing page module named `other`.After running `ionic g component test`, I import the automatically generated `ComponentsModule` into the `other.module.ts` and added it to the `imports` array.

```
import { ComponentsModule } from "../../components/components.module";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OtherPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OtherPage),
    ComponentsModule,

    ],
})
export class OtherPageModule {}
```

I then add the component selector to the page as `<test></test>`.

This results in an error :

```
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'test' is not a known element:
1. If 'test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("

<ion-content padding>
[ERROR ->]<test> </test>
</ion-content>
"): ng:///AppModule/OtherPage.html@16:0 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
'test' is not a known element:
1. If 'test' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

This does not work for me. I also tried to create an `module` for the test component and imported it in the same manner but this does not work for me.

I cant seem to find any documentation or examples for this.How are custom component imported in Ionic 3?

Comment: can you provide your whole code?

Comment: Please join my Ionic 3 chatroom - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153499/ionic-3

Comment: You need the selector of the [Component](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#selector) defined as "test"

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it:

1. Suppose, your *custom-component.ts* exports class `CustomComponent`.
2. import same in *custom-component.module.ts* as shown below:

   ```
   import { CustomComponent } from './custom-component';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       CustomComponent,
     ],
     imports: [
       IonicPageModule.forChild(CustomComponent),
     ],
     exports : [ CustomComponent ]
   })
   export class CustomComponentPageModule { }
   ```
3. Now import your custom component in the page you want it in, as shown below:

   ```
   import { ContentDrawerPageModule } from '../../../components/custom-component/custom-component.module';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       HelloWorldPage,
     ],
     imports: [
       IonicPageModule.forChild(HelloWorldPage),
       CustomComponentPageModule,
     ]
   })
   export class HelloWorldPageModule {}
   ```

And you have successfully imported your custom component *(`CustomComponent`)* to your page *(HelloWorldPage)*.

Comment: Thanks for removing the fluff @jps.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11560

> unfortunately there's no way to make lazy load component, directive, pipe. any way let us know if you manage it.

So you can import your ComponentsModule in your page.module.ts . Here is mine.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ComponentsModule } from ../../components/components.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    WoDetailsPage,

  ],
  imports: [
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(WoDetailsPage),
  ],
})
export class WoDetailsPageModule {}
```

Comment: [IonicForum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/rc-0-how-do-you-import-export-modules-into-your-app/65168/13) - Discussion Refer to the discussion posted by **yubin_zhu** Apparently, importing just IonicModule suffices without _forChild_ or _forRoot_ does the trick. As far as I tested, this worked for me. `@NgModule({ imports:[IonicModule], //no forRoot here declarations:[HomePage], exports:[HomePage], entryComponents:[HomePage] //<-- add all your module components to here })`

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it like below:

```
import { ComponentsModule } from "../../components/components.module";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OtherPage,
    ComponentsModule,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OtherPage),

    ],
  entryComponents: [
    ComponentsModule
  ]
})
export class OtherPageModule {}
```

Comment: I 've tried this but the component is  still unknown to the app

Answer (score 0):

You must export the `test` component.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TestComponent,
  ],
  imports: [],
  exports: [TestComponent]
})
export class ComponentModule {}
```

Comment: The component is already exported in the components.module.ts-

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add each component into your app.module.ts file and then declare as follows:

```
import { MyComp } from "../../components/my-comp/my-comp";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    OtherPage,
    MyComp
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(OtherPage)
    ],
})
export class OtherPageModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

After successfully using the [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA](https://angular.io/api/core/CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA) declarations in my modules and which forces you to name your selectors with a "-" dash, so I would have to use something like:

```
<MyPlayer-comp></MyPlayer-comp>
```

I was upset with this total non-sense from these frameworks camel-case freaks even though it worked and ngc no longer complained about "...is not a known element...".

I personally **prefer** to name everything the same (the class, the selector, the file, etc...)

I reverted to the following which is working with lazy-loading while I build for the web. (ionic cordova build browser --prod --release)

Your custom component module declarations:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
//
import { MyPlayerComp } from './MyPlayerComp ';
//
@NgModule({
    declarations: [MyPlayerComp ],
    imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(MyPlayerComp )],
    exports: [MyPlayerComp ],
})
export class MyPlayerCompModule { }
```

In the modules where you want to use your custom component use the following:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
//
import { PlyrView } from './PlyrView';
//
import { MyPlayerCompModule } from './MyPlayerComp.module' // 20180720
//
@NgModule({
    declarations: [PlyrView],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(PlyrView),
        MyPlayerCompModule,                      // <<<<<
    ],                
    exports: [PlyrView],
})
export class PlyrViewModule { }
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, by following the below link :
http://evalogical.com/blog/components-ionic-framework-3

1. Import the component in the `home.ts` file like this,
   `import { MyComponent } from '../../components/my/my';`
2. In `home.module.ts` import the `ComponentsModule` and add it in the imports,like this.

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';  
   import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';  
   import { HomePage } from './home';  
   import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';  
   @NgModule({  
   declarations: [  
   HomePage,  
   ],  
   imports: [  
   IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),  
   ComponentsModule  
   ],  
   })  
   export class HomePageModule {}
   ```
3. Import the IonicPageModule in the `components.module.ts` file and here we need to import `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in schemas like this.

   ```
   import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';  
   import { MyComponent } from './my/my';  
   import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';  
   @NgModule({  
   declarations: [MyComponent],  
   imports: [IonicPageModule.forChild(MyComponent)],  
   exports: [MyComponent],  
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]  
   })  
   export class ComponentsModule {}
   ```
4. Remove the line
   `import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';` from the `app.module.ts` file   and instead add the following line `import { HomePageModule } from '../pages/home/home.module';`
5. Now you can use the selector of the component as a html tag in the `home.html` file

Answer (score 0):

If *myComponent.ts* is your component.

Then you can remove the generated module by the commands *ionic generate* (if you dont use lazy loading) and add the following directly in app.module.ts

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
      ]
      entryComponents: [
        MyComponent
      ] });
```

And *myComponent.ts* looks like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sheduler',
  templateUrl: 'sheduler.html'
})
export class ShedulerComponent {}
```